# SQL Server 2008 priority on different columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to clean data based on the following criteria. I have 3 columns `PhoneNumber`, `phoneType` and `phoneStatus`. The order of priority is as follows:

- Phone Status = Do Not Call
- Phone Type = Work Cell-No Consent, Cell - No Consent, Work Cell, Cell, Cell w/Permission, Work, Spouse Work, Home,  Spouse Home, Third party Number, Fax
- Phone Status = Bad, Good, Unknown.

I am trying to use `row_number()` but it didn't work.

For example if I have

```
PhoneTypeID   PhoneStatusID   PhoneNumber
------------------------------------------
Work          Unknown         9999999999    
Cell          Do not call     9999999999
```

I want to delete the first row

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want to delete rows based in PhoneStatus?

Comment: well, not just phone status. Phone status with Do not Call takes higher priority. So I want to keep it. Next comes phone Type in that given order and finally again phone status with Bad, Good or Unknown.
So if I have 
PhoneTypeID   PhoneStatusID   PhoneNumber
------------------------------------------
Cell          Unknown         9999999999    
Home       Bad                 9999999999

Comment: I would want to keep the first one and delete the second one